# Error "Undefined control sequence." in .cls file

Tags: overleaf

I'm using technojournal.cls from http://www.techno-press.org. When I compile the main tex file in overleaf, it shows error

```
<recently read> \setremarkmarkup
1.904\setremarkmarkup
{(#2)}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If youhavemisspelled it (e.g.,' \hobx'),type 'I' and the correctspelling (e.g., I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,and I'll forget about whatever was undefned.
```

The code in technojournal.cls is as follow:

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% refereee %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \if@referee
    \RequirePackage{changes}
    \setremarkmarkup{(#2)}
    \pagestyle{journalstyle}
    \else
    \RequirePackage[final]{changes}
    \setremarkmarkup{(#2)}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \fi
    \makeatother
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The LaTeX template downloaded from http://www.techno-press.com/papers/Authors'%20Guide.zip contains some rather old package .sty files, so this template may not be compatible with newer TeX Lives (Overleaf currently uses TL2020 as the default TL). You may want to try changing your Overleaf project's TeX Live version to, say, TL2017. https://www.overleaf.com/blog/new-feature-select-your-tex-live-compiler-version

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem perfectly.